# Keep DialogFragment in front of all activities(even the ones created after showing the DialogFragment )

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` that is shown in some situtation and it represents a pin request to unlock access to the app.

There is a scenario in my app where i start an activity and if some conditions are met it shows the `DialogFragment`(Launched from a BaseActivity) asking for a pin, but in the meanwhile the `Activity A` starts another a `Activity B`, and the `DialogFragment` gets behind it.

The sequence of events is

> 1- ActivityA is started
>
> 2- DialogFragment is shown
>
> 3- ActivityA starts ActivityB, and DialogFragment gets behind.

I want to keep the `DialogFragment` in front of everything even it a new activity is started after the fragment appears.

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(cancelable: Boolean = false): LockCodeFragment {
        val frag = PinCodeFragment()
        frag.isCancelable = cancelable
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            frag.dialog?.window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY)
            frag.dialog?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY)
        } else {
            frag.dialog?.window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT)
            frag.dialog?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT)
        }
        return frag
    }
```

I tried to set the dialog to have the type system alert or application overlay when i instanciate the fragment, but with no success.

Is there a way to keep a `DiaglogFragment` in front of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, this is not possible to my knowledge, because Fragments are being managed by the `FragmentManager` which is unique for each Activity. I think that the best you could do is remember if that fragment is shown somewhere (using `SharedPreferences` or even a field in the `Application` subclass) and then, when the another activity starts, check that value to possibly display the dialog again.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.bringToFront()
```

Makes the view to comes to front

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a BaseActivity.
2. Add your dialog show condition in BaseActivity
3. Extend all other activity with BaseActivity.
4. Prevent dialog close as below

To prevent dialog box from getting dismissed on back key pressed use this

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

And to prevent dialog box from getting dismissed on outside touch use this

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Yes i have a BaseActivity , and it is there that i call the DialogFragment, but it gets behind activity B when it B starts

Comment: Block the user on dialog by using above two method. So Activity B should not open by user.

Comment: The ActivityB inst open by the user, its automatic if ActivityA has some conditions met when it starts.

Comment: Then, Before stating Activity B check that Dialog fragment is display or not.If not then only open activity B.

Comment: This is not correct. With every instance of a new Activity, you get a whole new instance of BaseActivity. To my knowledge, the FragmentManager is not static (thus common for all activities).